# How to deploy an application in IBM websphere server with a azure devops pipeline's?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, websphere

I have an application in repo of azure devops and I want create a pipeline that connects to IBM websphere server to deploy it with azure release.

The WAS is onpremise, but the repository azure is in cloud and I need automate the deploy of an application.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a build pipeline to build your application and create an artifact (e.g., a WAR file).
2. Ensure that your Azure DevOps agents can communicate directly with the WebSphere server over the network. If the hosted agent can't access your WebSphere server, you can try to use [a self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#install) which can access the server.
3. You can install the [IBM WebSphere Application Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.ibm-websphere) extension in your organization.  Then you can deploy applications to IBM WebSphere with the IBM WebSphere Deployment task.

[image]